# Mysql full text seach not working for 2 or 3 characters

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I created Fulltext seach index and set `ft_max_word_len=1.`

When I do:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
MATCH (title,description,content) AGAINST ('ニ') 
ORDER BY tablename.start_time LIMIT 50
```

or when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (title,description,content) 
AGAINST ('ニュース') ORDER BY tablename.start_time LIMIT 50
```

It show 50 record.

but when I do:

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (title,description,content) 
 AGAINST ('ニュ') ORDER BY tablename.start_time LIMIT 50
```

or when I do:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (title,description,content) 
AGAINST ('ニュー') ORDER BY tablename.start_time LIMIT 50
```

It shows empty result.

Can you explain why?

Comment: Did you restart mysql and rebuit the indexes after changing the `set ft_max_word_len` `repair table tablename quick`

Comment: yes, I did. That why I can search with one char

Comment: Maybe I know why. Because Japanese don't have space between words, then mysql doesn't know where is start or end of words. It's make wrong indexing